# Design REST API for tree

Tags: rest, tree, resources

I am thinking about how to design a REST api for a tree like structure.
I read already this one: [How should a REST URL schema look like for a tree hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150171/how-should-a-rest-url-schema-look-like-for-a-tree-hierarchy) and a lot of other resources, but still am on the fence between several possibilities.

This is my tree (root is artificial as it is only displayed for UI purposes, the datamodel has no root).

```
root ___ |credit| __>10000__ |status| __=gold__ || = helpFast|| || = callBack ||
                             |status| __=silver__ || = helpFast|| 
     ___ |node| __branch__ |another_node| __another_branch__ ||result_node||
  ...
```

Where **| |** is a node and __ >xxx__ is a condition on a branch, so the first line reads as:
If Credit > 10000 and status = gold then helpFast and callBack.

From a very abstract point of view this consists of nodes and branches. So my first Idea is to have two resources:

- /tree/treename/node with PUT, POST and DELETE
- /tree/treename/branch with PUT, POST and DELETE

and one GET resource:

- /tree/treename

which returns the whole data as one.

This is all we need for now.

However, you can see that we have nodes here with different meanings.

First there is a condition node (credit) with a condition branch (>10000) which belongs together and then there is a result node (a leaf basically) that may contain many assignments and another special field that is unique to the assignment and does not exist in a condition.

So another approach is to have:

- /tree/name/conditionNode PUT, POST, DELETE
- /tree/name/branch PUT, POST, DELETE
- /tree/name/leave PUT, POST, DELETE
- /tree/name/result PUT, POST, DELETE (just as a convenience for the leave)

Or maybe use something completely different.

I find all solutions that I came up with having some disadvantages, so I am open for every idea and discussion points or considerations.

Thanks,
Sven

**EDIT** When using the plain `node`, `branch` approach I would identify the transferred data by a `type` key value pair that would contain types like conditionNode, resultNode, result and may be some more. This could map to possible resources.

Comment: I would guess JSON can represent a tree rather nicely.  Why aren't you using that?

Comment: JSON is what I use to represent the data, but which REST endpoints do I offer?

Comment: REST means HTTP verbs; URLs should refer to the resource you want.  Hard to design the whole thing here.